# Traverse the XML using Attribute Value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have to take all the child nodes of the following node.

```
<Contact Enabled="true" Hash="1105403056" Id="-1" Index="0"  UserTypeName="Name" ViewClassName="employeeContact">
```

I'm using the following code but the result is always null

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("alarm1.xml");
var tabNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Contact [@UserTypeName=Name]");
```

The same thing works if I put this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("alarm1.xml");
var tabNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Contact [@Hash=1105403056]");
```

Can someone help me here please? Tell me what is wrong in the first method?

Comment: Have you tried this `//Contact[@UserTypeName='Name']`? What is `//UIControl` by the way?

Comment: Its nothing. I edited the question for clear understanding. My bad I'm sorry.

Comment: Oh my god! That totally worked. Thank you so much.:)

Comment: For your understanding. It should select all `Contact` having `userTypeName='Name'`. If you are sure that every time you will be getting single node in result then you could use `SelectSingleNode` as well. Which should return single contact element.